# How to get error messages while using Twisted reactor?

Tags: python, twisted

I have implemented a server and several clients using `Twisted` (in Python). Now, as I develop my server and the code gets more complicated I need to carefully resolve possible bugs. However, because of the `Twisted` reactor (that's my guess), I never get any error messages, even when there are obvious flaws in the code. I am wondering if there is any best practice or solution for getting error messages on the consule while running a `Twisted` reactor?
Just for your information, I'm using lineReceiver and serverFactory, and defferedToThread to run another thread in parallel to the networking part of the server. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Enable logging.

```
from twisted.python.log import startLogging
from sys import stdout

startLogging(stdout)

...
```

Or use `twistd` which enables it automatically for you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had enabled logging already, but still there are cases that error messages aren't shown. Do you possibly have any guess why that might be?

Comment: Why do you think error messages exist if they don't show up?